# Why does `sudo` fail in a simple container on Fedora 32?

Tags: fedora, docker, sudo, pam, podman

I am scratching my head trying to figure this one out.

Under a freshly installed Fedora 32, the following minimal container does not execute properly:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y sudo && yum clean all -y
RUN useradd -m test
RUN sudo -u test true
```

To test this, execute:

```
podman build .
```

The result is:

```
STEP 4: RUN sudo -u test true
sudo: PAM account management error: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
Error: error building at STEP "RUN sudo -u test true": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

Now I am wondering, what makes fedora 32 special? I am pretty sure this used to work under 31.  Since the version of `sudo` being involved and its environment is unchanged, the only difference could be podman. But what does podman have to do with the invocation of `sudo` inside the container (or PAM in general)?

(this question was tagged with "docker" because I cannot create the tag "podman")

Comment: I can't resolve your issue, but 1) I just tested this on Fedora 33 and can't recreate and 2) I created [tag:podman] for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is what I figured out after many painful hours of debugging.

1. I had migrated to a new laptop before trying this. I did this by copying `/home`  from the old to the new laptop.
2. The image cache on my new home directory contained some kind of fault. `podman` did not complain or try to re-download the image, but I could see (by comparison to another machine) that the hash was different. Inside the image the `/etc/shadow` was missing - I have no clue why or how that could have happened, though.
3. After completely wiping any `podman` cache and re-downloading, I got the correct images and everything worked again.

So this must have been a very specific error when copying podman images from Fedora 31 to 32. The image was somewhat intact. I could run it. But it completely missed at least one crucial file. Quite bizarre.